# Three columns with 33% width and margins/padding. Why is last column breaking?

Tags: css, html

Am trying to give width of the page in %.

So i tried  the following code

```
<div id="mainContent" style="height: 350px">
               <div class="grid4">

                </div>
                <div class="grid4">

                </div>
                <div class="grid4">

                </div>

            </div>
```

and Grid4 css below

```
.grid4
{
    Width: 33%;
    float:left;
}
```

and the Main Content width in `100%.`

Now i am trying to give `padding or margin in percentage` for any of the `grid4` it is pushing the next Div one down.

What property should i be using to give inner padding for Width ?

Thanks

Comment: You have three grids of 33% width which totals 99%.   If you add even 1% padding, you will have a new total of 102% (or more).  So the divs will wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the padding or margins are applied to the `.grid4` columns, then their size will be added to the widths of the columns: 33% + 33% + 33% + (whatever the combined padding and margins are) = ?? (something most likely larger than 100%). That's why the columns are breaking.

If you apply the padding or margins to a child element of each column, the size will not be added to the widths of the columns. 33% + 33% + 33% = 99%.

If you do need to apply the padding or margins to the columns, then you'll have to reduce the widths to an amount that will add up to 100% or less, when combined with the padding or margins.

Comment: So Div inside Grid4 and i do things.Right ?

Comment: @user2067567: That should work without breaking the columns, yes. That's the easiest way to do it. That way you can tackle the margins and padding entirely separately from the widths, with no risk of the margins and padding causing the columns to break.

Answer (score 3):

In standard CSS box model padding adds it's value to the width of the container.(width + padding + border = actual visible/rendered width of box)

So your grid4 width = 33% + padding. That's why it pushes it down.

You could use CSS Box Sizing - which allows you to have padding added to a container and still have it's actual width unchanged to what you specify.

```
#mainContent{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
            box-sizing: border-box;     
}
```

Then it should work as you want it to work.

Otherwise you need to calculate your padding and width for each grid4 to be total of 33%.

Comment: Margins would still occupy space outside of the column widths. But this would at least prevent padding from breaking the columns.

Comment: Sure, you need to have margin set to 0 or included in calculations for the space of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I've found is to wrap the 3-up div's each in a second div. The wrappers are set to 33% width and then the containers have the margin applied.

CSS like this:

```
.one_third {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.boxes {
    background: #8888ff;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And a the HTML like this.

```
<div class="one_third">
    <div class="boxes">
        Hi there!
    </div>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
    <div class="boxes">
        Hi there!
    </div>
</div>
<div class="one_third">
    <div class="boxes">
        Hi there!
    </div>
</div>
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkmh56uy/